# is there any way to add a readerview in inapp expo browser or any other inapp browser in react native app

Tags: react-native

I am using an expo browser as in app browser.I need to impliment a readermode in the browser how can i do it. this is the docs "https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/"

I tried reader mode but the package is not supporting.

````
                    <Text numberOfLines={3} style={{ fontSize: 14,fontWeight:'bold' }}
                     onPress={() => WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(item.url)}
                    >{item.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10,color:"#B6B6B4",fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.author}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10,color:"#B6B6B4",fontWeight:'bold' }}>{item.publishedAt}</Text>
                  </Body>```


i want a webview with reader mode. for both ios and android.Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you install expo module??

You should install `expo install expo-web-browser`

and  The text does not have onPress. You can use `TouchableOpacity`

```js
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

  async _handlePressButtonAsync(url){
    await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url);
  };
...
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this._handlePressButtonAsync(item.url)}
        >
        <Text numberOfLines={3} style={{ fontSize: 14,fontWeight:'bold' }}>{item.title}
        </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: the browser works fine i need is a reader mode like in safari and simplified mode in chrome.